Markers Positioned Below the Surface of .glb Model in Three.js
I'm working on a Three.js project (React) using the @react-three/fiber and @react-three/drei libraries. My goal is to place markers on the surface of a terrain .glb model based on specific coordinates. However, I'm facing an issue where the markers are being positioned below the model instead of on its surface.
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { PresentationControls, Stage, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";

function Model({ setLandscape, ...props }) {
  const gltf = useGLTF("/landscape_free.glb");

  useEffect(() => {
    setLandscape(gltf.scene);
  }, [gltf, setLandscape]);

  return <primitive object={gltf.scene} {...props} scale={[0.8, 0.8, 0.8]} />;
}

function Marker({ initialPosition, landscape }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (landscape && ref.current) {
      const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      const direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0); // Cast downward

      const positionAdjusted = initialPosition.clone();
      positionAdjusted.y += 1; // Move ray origin slightly above the model

      raycaster.set(positionAdjusted, direction);

      const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(landscape, true);
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        ref.current.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
      } else {
        console.warn("No intersection found for marker at", initialPosition);
      }
    }
  }, [initialPosition, landscape]);

  const { scene } = useGLTF("/pointer.glb");
  return <primitive object={scene} ref={ref} scale={[0.01, 0.01, 0.01]} />;
}

const coordinates = [
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.034, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-0.4, 0.2, -0.4),
  new THREE.Vector3(-0.4, 0.1, -0.4),
];

function Map() {
  const [landscape, setLandscape] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (landscape) {
      const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(landscape);
      console.log("Landscape bounding box:", boundingBox);
      console.log("Min:", boundingBox.min);
      console.log("Max:", boundingBox.max);
    }
  }, [landscape]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas
        dpr={[1, 2]}
        shadows
        camera={{ fov: 45 }}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          touchAction: "none",
        }}
      >
        <PresentationControls
          speed={1.5}
          global
          zoom={1}
          polar={[-0.1, Math.PI / 4]}
        >
          <Stage environment="sunset">
            {coordinates.map((coord, index) => (
              <Marker
                key={index}
                initialPosition={coord}
                landscape={landscape}
              />
            ))}
            <Model scale={0.8} setLandscape={setLandscape} />
          </Stage>
        </PresentationControls>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;


My glb model is this one:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/landscape-free-05a23d3d1c1d4e78aee7fc9257bf5332
Problems:

I have three coordinates but only one marker is shown.
Marker is shown below the model

How it is displayed in the browser
I tried Raycasting to show it above the model but it did not work.
